# OpenSSL verify PFX password OK

Tags: openssl, passwords, pfx, pkcs#12

I want to verify that a given password for a given PFX file works. I tried with

```
openssl pkcs12 -in CERT.pfx -password pass:PASSWORD -info
```

but the problem is it keeps asking me for the PEM password. All I want it to output is a simple result like password OK, or general info about the file, otherwise 'invalid password'.

This will be executed from another process, so I need to avoid any interactive password prompts.

Couldn't find anything about this with Google.

Answer (score 17):

Found it:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in CERT.pfx -password pass:PASSWORD -info -nokeys
```